# Django signals as IPC

Tags: python, django, ipc, twisted

So I have written a websocket application in Twisted.  The application is a basic game between a number of users, but trying to use the web socket for setup and record saving is painful, so I was looking into using Django based rendering for the supplementary information (as in standings, game setup, lobby list, etc) and leave the websockets for the real action.  I know I can use some basic IPC functionality to have the Django requests signal the Twisted application, but I was curious if the Django signal system would also work across applications as a simple form of IPC...

Answer (score 2):

No. Django signals are restricted to a single Python interpreter. You'll need to put together something else (sockets, JSON-RPC, XMPP, etc.) in order to perform IPC.